# in TYPO3 6.1 and tx_news, how to enforce language of displayed posts

Tags: typo3, typoscript, typo3-6.1.x

I have the following TS [based on the manual](http://docs.typo3.org/typo3cms/extensions/news/2.3.0/Main/Tutorial/IntegrationWithTs/Index.html) to display a tx_news list / latest view via TypoScript.

```
temp.latestnews = USER
temp.latestnews {

      userFunc = tx_extbase_core_bootstrap->run
      extensionName = News
      pluginName = Pi1

      switchableControllerActions {
            News {
              1 = list
            }
      }

      settings {
            limit = 5
        detailPid = 123
        overrideFlexformSettingsIfEmpty := addToList(detailPid)
        startingpoint = 456
      }
}
```

In contrary to when using a plugin, all translations are displayed. 
There should only be posts from the current language. I can't find the setting to enforce that. Or what could be wrong?

Comment: What is your sys_language_mode?

Comment: I had it on default (unset), in combination with `sys_language_overlay =1`. Now I've set it to `sys_language_mode = strict`. The news work as expected now. Did I trade off something else with that? And does the combination with `sys_language_overlay =1` make sense at all?

Comment: @lorenz: is it really necessery to set `sys_language_mode = strict`? I've never had to do that before, and it's being very ... strict

Comment: actually, sys_langauge_mode = strict terminates about all reasonable language fallback behaviour throughout the site. I still don't understand how the news plugin can't be set independently to be limited to one lang